# How can I make my divs grow physically as needed as I add names into child divs (native JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I am creating a random group generator. I am about done, but I need to create a space to display the names. I am trying to find a way so that as more characters are added, the width of the div it is in grows and if more names are added, the height of the div grows.

Also, all of these divs that will be growing will be inside of another div, if there are too many divs inside of this parent div, stuff gets hidden and some weird stuff happens, so that needs to grow as well with the children divs.

Note: I'm still not sure what counts as a child and a parent, so I'm sorry if this language is incorrect.

Note: This issue will most probably be resolved on lines `59` to `90` which is defined by the function `createGroups()`.

```js
const inputArticle = document.querySelector('#input-article');
const inputForm = document.querySelector('#input-form');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
const groupOptions = document.querySelector('select[ name="group-options" ]');
const createTeamsButton = document.querySelector('#create-teams-button');
const outputArticle = document.querySelector('#output-article');
const outputMainDiv = document.querySelector('#output-main-div');

let peopleArray = [];
let numberPeople = 0;
let rowNumber = 0;
let groupNumber = 1;
let maxPeopleInGroup = 0;
let maxNumberGroups = 0;

function addRow(person) {
    let row = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
    let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    let removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    
    removeButton.dataset = person;
    removeButton.innerText = `Remove ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}`;
    removeButton.setAttribute("type", "button");

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        peopleArray = peopleArray.filter(p => p != person);
        row.remove();
    })

    cell1.innerText = person.firstName;
    cell2.innerText = person.lastName;
    cell3.appendChild(removeButton);
}

function createNames(event) {
    let person = {
        firstName:  document.getElementById(`firstName`).value,
        lastName: document.getElementById(`lastName`).value
    }

    event.target.reset();
    addRow(person);
    peopleArray.push(person);
    numberPeople++;
    //alert(JSON.stringify(peopleArray));
}

function submit() {
    if (groupOptions.value != "") {
        inputArticle.classList.add("hidden");
        outputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
        createGroups();
    }
}

function createGroups() {
    maxPeopleInGroup = groupOptions.value;
    maxNumberGroups = Math.floor(maxPeopleInGroup / peopleArray.length);
    let divWidth = maxPeopleInGroup //This is just a placeholder for now
    let divHeight = maxPeopleInGroup //This is just a placeholder for now 

    while (numberPeople / maxPeopleInGroup > maxNumberGroups) {
        maxNumberGroups++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < maxNumberGroups; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", `group${groupNumber}`);
        div.style.width = `${divWidth}vw`;
        div.style.height = `${divHeight}vh`;
        //div.style.background = "red";
        div.style.textAlign = "center";
        div.style.alignItems = "center";
        div.style.fontFamily = "Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif";
        div.style.fontSize = "18pt";
        div.style.fontWeight = "400";
        div.style.border = "1px solid black";
        outputMainDiv.appendChild(div);
        groupNumber++;

        for (let k = 0; k < maxPeopleInGroup; k++) {
            let index = Math.round(Math.random() * peopleArray.length);
            div.innerHTML += `${peopleArray[index].firstName} ${peopleArray[index].lastName} </br>`
        }
    }
}     

inputArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
outputArticle.classList.add("hidden");

window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        if (firstName.value && lastName.value) {
            createNames(event);
        }    
    }
}, false)

inputForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
   createNames(event);
   event.target.reset();
})

createTeamsButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
```

```css
#input-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

table {
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 10vmin;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: 800;
}

input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#group {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#output-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#output-main-div {
    width: 95vw; 
    height: 95vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="input-article">
            <form method="dialog" id="input-form">
                <table id="table" border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name:</th>
                            <th>Last Name:</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody></tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="first-name" type="text" required placeholder="First Name" id="firstName"></td>
                            <td><input name="last-name" type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" id="lastName"></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit">Add Person</button>
                                <button type="reset">Clear Names</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table> 
            </form><br>

            <div id="group">
                <p>Number of people per group:&nbsp;</p>
                <select name = "group-options" required>
                    <option value="">--Select Answer--</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>
            </div>    

            <div id="buttons">
                <button id="create-teams-button">Randomize Teams</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="output-article">
            <div id="output-main-div"></div>
        </article>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `div` height will automatically adjust to the height of the content within them. `span` elements will automatically adjust to the width of the content within them.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you describe: "as more characters are added, the width of the div it is in grows and if more names are added, the height of the div grows." is the standard behaviour of HTML.

You have to add CSS to change this behavior and break it.

In your example, the input-fields are too small for the text inside. The reason are these lines from your CSS:

```
input {
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 5vmin;

    font-size: 18pt;
}
```

The size of the font is in absolute terms with the unit pt.

The width and height of the input field is relative to the size of the viewport with the unit vmin.

so for smaller viewports, the with and height will be smaller than needed to show the font.

```css
    input {
        width: 50vmin;
        height: 5vmin;

        font-size: 18pt;
    }
```

```html
<input value="Sample Text">
```

Comment: *The behaviour you describe: "as more characters are added, the width of the div it is in grows and if more names are added, the height of the div grows." is the standard behaviour of HTML.* <-- That's 1/2 right. `div` elements are 100% the width of their parent element. They (block elements) do not adjust their width to their content. `span` (inline) elements do that.

Comment: true. I'll adapte the answer